# Overlay data structure?

Tags: data-structures, haskell, pandoc

I have a nested, mutual recursive [data structure](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pandoc-types/1.8.0.2/doc/html/Text-Pandoc-Definition.html), and want to associate computational expensive values to some of the nodes. Actually, I want to temporarily link the Blocks in a [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) document to the list of words occuring in that block.

Unattractive options I want to avoid:

- extending the Block data type such that it includes the word list, which boils down to creating a new extended Pandoc datatype with lots of (fragile) boiler plate code
- mapping blocks to word lists; which is suboptimal as the blocks are too complex to serve efficiently as keys

The direction I am seeking a solution is some kind of overlay data structure that includes the extended Blocks, but with the underlying data types untouched, so that I can still use the extensive Pandoc libraries. But perhaps this is not the Haskell Way of Thinking...

**Post scriptum 2011-06-12**:

As the comments show, I probably overestimated the cost of the Map approach, partly based on wrong assumptions. Indeed: "there is nothing more deceptive than an obvious fact".

Anyway, I accept the answer of hammar, because it illustrates how to create an extensible data type.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use a `Map` to store the associations between nodes?

Comment: @Don Stewart: Do you mean a Data.Map from Block to WordList? Yes, but my concern is that a Block as key would be too complex a data structure. Typically it represents a whole paragraph and its formatting, including possibly other Blocks.

Comment: Hash the block before storing as a key?

Comment: Or just use the HashMap (from unordered-containers).

Comment: @luqui: I'm not concerned that much about the size of the keys (most often they will be shared with the source Pandoc structure), but about the cost of comparing the keys. Actually, computing the hash and using that as key is only doing explicitly what Data.Map does behind the scenes (I assume that it uses hashes internally). The major cost is then the hashing, I think.

Comment: Before dismissing the idea of having a Block as the key, perhaps you should try it.

Comment: @sleepyMonad Bad assumption.  Data.Map does not hash behind the scenes.  It just compares, using the `Ord` instance, pairs of keys in a tree (for insertion).  The package I suggested, unordered-containers (module Data.HashMap.{Strict,Lazy}), will hash the keys.

Comment: @TomMD I stand corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add stuff to an existing data type when it was not designed to be extensible, so you're going to have to rely on some external structure such as a `Map` to associate the word lists to each block.

If you could change the datatype however, you could make it extensible by generalizing the recursion in the data type. Let's say you have a recursive data type like this:

```
data Tree = Leaf | Fork String Tree Tree
```

We can add a parameter for the recursive usage of `Tree`:

```
data GenTree t = Leaf | Fork String t t
```

Now, to have a plain tree like the original, we take the fixed point of this type:

```
data Fix a = Fix (a (Fix a))
type Tree = Fix GenTree
```

Now, you can extend the type with additional data at each recursive site. Here's how to make a type for labelled trees:

```
data Labelled t = Labelled Int (GenTree t)
type LabelledTree = Fix Labelled

strLength :: GenTree t -> Int
strLength Leaf = 0
strLength (Fork str _ _) = length str

label :: Tree -> LabelledTree
label (Fix tree) = Fix $ Labelled (strLength tree) (fmap label tree)

instance Functor GenTree where
    fmap f Leaf = Leaf
    fmap f (Fork s l r) = Fork s (f l) (f r)
```

Comment: I'm halfway in understanding this answer; already +1 for advanced type wizardry...

I can see that

type Tree = Fix GenTree = Fix (GenTree (Fix GenTree)) = Fix (Leaf | Fork Str (Fix GenTree) (Fix GenTree)) = Fix (Leaf | Fork Str Tree Tree) = Fix Tree,

hence Gentree must be equal to Tree. Is this something like tying the knot on type level?

Comment: @sleepyMonad. Correct, it is analogous to using [`fix`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-Function.html#v:fix) to make a function recursive. For example, take a non-recursive factorial function with a parameter in place of the recursion: `fac f n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * f (n-1)`. Now, use `fix` to make it recursive: `fix fac 10`

Comment: @sleepyMonad: It can be done with the extensions `FlexibleContexts` and `UndecidableInstances`. For example, for `Show`: `deriving instance (Show (a (Fix a))) => Show (Fix a)`. (This also uses `StandaloneDeriving` to get the compiler to generate it for me.)